# Подскажите методику решения задачи

Tags: c

Ребят, подскажите как лучше решить задачу .Дано множество слов.Определить , можно ли расположить эти слова в таком прядке , что бы каждое следующее слово начиналось с буквы , н которую оканчивается предыдущее. Что использовать для решения задачи? Может стоит графы или таблицы?

Comment: Стройте граф, а потом ищите путь, проходящий однократно по всем рёбрам.

Comment: А как найти этот путь ? Есть какое то свойство пар?

Answer (score 0):

Кажется логичным построить ориентированный граф, в котором вершины графа - слова, а ребро между вершиной a и b существует если слово a заканчивается на букву на которую начинается b.

Решением задачи будет эйлеров путь в полученном графе. Эйлеров путь в графе существует тогда и только тогда, когда граф связный и число вершин с нечетной степенью равно 0 или 2.

Степень вершины графа - кол-во инцидентных ей дуг.

Вариант алгоритма для проверки является ли граф связным: https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: Проще наоборот. Узлы - буквы (первая и последняя), рёбра - слова.

Comment: Пожалуйста, перенесите код по ссылки и нужную информацию, а ссылку, оставьте в качестве источника.

Comment: Это какая-то белиберда. Во-первых, Эйлеров путь по определению допускает повторное посещение вершин. Данная задача НЕ допускает повторное использование слов. Поэтому Эйлеров путь в полученном графе НЕ будет решением задачи. Путь здесь нужен именно Гамильтонов, а не Эйлеров. (Во-вторых, упомянутый вами критерий существования Эйлерова пути применим только к неориентированным графам, а вы сами предложили строить ориентированный.)